# Implications of the Principle of continuous induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

The Principle of continuous induction is an extension of usual [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to the set of non-negative real numbers $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and it goes like this:

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ have the following properties:
>
> 1. $0\in A$,
> 2. if $x\in A$ there is $\varepsilon>0$ with $[x,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq A$,
> 3. if $x\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $[0,x)\subseteq A$, then $x\in A$.
>
> Then $A = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

What are examples of fundamental results in real analysis that can be derived from the above principle?

Comment: It is equivalent to the supremum property, so anything dependent on the supremum property (ie, practically all of real analysis) could be recast in terms of it.

Comment: There are a few proofs using real induction here http://math.uga.edu/~pete/instructors_guide_shorter.pdf

Comment: Thanks @BlairAzzopardi!